# sp::spTransform : non-finite transformation detected

Tags: r, r-sp

I want to apply a Mollweide projection to some lat/lon coordinates.

```
set.seed(41)
n <- 200
s <- data.frame(lon = rnorm(n, 0, 180),
                lat = rnorm(n, 0, 30))
coordinates(s) = ~lon + lat
projection(s) <- '+proj=longlat'
plot(s)
```

Changing the projection throws an error:

```
s <- spTransform(s, CRS('+proj=moll'))

non finite transformation detected:
     lon lat  
Error in spTransform(s, CRS("+proj=moll")) : failure in points 
Additionally: Warning:
In spTransform(s, CRS("+proj=moll")) : 1 projected point(s) not finite
```

I am new to geo data and the `sp` package and do not understand what is happening here and how to fix it.

Comment: With the random seed you provided, your example produces longitudes ranging from -390 to 598 (normal distribution, mean = 0, 1 sd = 180). This is what is causing the error because it is expecting values between -180 and 180

Comment: YOu probably meant to do `runif` (uniformly distributed numbers between upper and lower) instead of `rnorm` (normally disributed numbers with mean and variance, potentially unbounded). Or maybe you need to drop anything outside +/-180, or map them onto +/-180?

Comment: okay, so my mistake was assuming that -720=-360=0=360=720 e.g. for longitude. thanks.